# why isn't it iterating through the whole loop of strings in that sentence? i intend to write all the lower case letters?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def up_low(s): 
    capital= ()
    for alpha in s:
        if alpha == alpha.lower():
            return (alpha)
        else:
            continue


s = 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'
up_low(s)
```

Comment: Try googling `islower()` in python. `return [c for c in s if c.islower()]` may help

Answer (score 1):

Because you `return` from your function - this leaves it after the first lower case character.

You need to collect the lowercases and return **after** processing *all* of them:

```
def up_low(s): 
    capital= []  # list
    for alpha in s:
        if alpha == alpha.lower():
            capital.append(alpha) 
    return ''.join(capital) 

s = 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'
up_low(s)
```

Or as list comp:

```
s = 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'
low = ''.join( (c for c in s if c.islower()) )
```

There is a difference between `c == c.lower()` and `c.islower()`, the comparison will be true
for `' '` or `','` as well - `c.islower()` returns `False` in that case.

Hence the different outputs:

```
ello r. ogers, how are you this fine uesday?       # c == c.lower()

ellorogershowareyouthisfineuesday                  # c.islower()
```